# AIR 3.0 JSON - How to loop through / count number of objects?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, air

Why does  `trace(length)` return 1? I expected it to be 3.

How would I loop through each `screen` object?

```
appData:Object = JSON.parse   {

"screen":
{
    "type": "Title",
    "title":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    },
    "content":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    }
},

"screen":
{
    "type": "Text",
    "title":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    },
    "content":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    }
},

"screen":
{
    "type": "Map",
    "title":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    },
    "content":
    {
        "en":"",
        "ae":""
    }
}
};

var length:uint = 0;
for ( var s:* in appData)
{
length++
}
trace(length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your JSON structure.  You're using the "screen" property name multiple times, and these need to be unique.  Alternatively, you could use an Array structure here.